# get notification or alerts when new VMs is created on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

HI is there a way to set alerts or notification, to send out when new VMs is created on Azure portal.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

As Thiago said, we can use Activity Log alerts to achieve it.

We can set it here:
[image]

[image]

In this way, when we create Azure VM in this rsource group, we will get the email.

More information about activity log alert, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-activity-log-alerts).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Azure Monitor and check for Activity Log alerts:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-overview-alerts

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested you can use Azure Monitor to achieve this. If you wish to trigger a Logic App or Azure function when a resource is created, you can explore Event Grids as another option.